# Elasticsearch/Lucene Regex fquery/query_string not returning all documents

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, nest

I currently have this mapping in Elasticsearch that I am indexing with a `not_analyzed` field:

```
PUT /twitter/_mapping/tweet
{
    "tweet": {
        "properties" : {
            "user" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}


PUT /twitter/tweet/1
{
    "user": "CNN"
}
PUT /twitter/tweet/2
{
    "user": "cnn"
}
PUT /twitter/tweet/3
{
    "user": "Cnn"
}
PUT /twitter/tweet/4
{
    "user": "cNN"
}
PUT /twitter/tweet/5
{
    "user": "CnN"
}
```

I want to search on this index with a case-insensitive filter like so (generated through NEST, so not too flexible in changing this query syntax):

```
POST /twitter/tweet/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "fquery": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "user:/[cC][nN][nN]/"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query only returns 1 documents though: `"user": "cnn"` (lowercase), not all of the documents.

Why is this? The same query with `"query": "user:CNN"` returns the correct document with the correct casing (uppercase).

**EDIT**: Also, if I remove the document with `cnn` (lowercase), the query returns nothing.

**EDIT 2**: In the case that this is a problem with my NEST code, here's the code used to generate the query:

```
// property path would be something like "user". queryTerm would be something like "cnn"
filterDescriptor.Query(
  q =>
    q.QueryString(
      d =>
        d.Query(string.Format("{0}:{1}", propertyPath,
          GetCaseInsentitiveRegexExpression(queryTerm))))); // returns something like /[cC][nN][nN]/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `lowercase_expanded_terms:false`. By default [lowercase_expanded_terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) is set to `true` which lower-cases wildcard,regexp queries.

Example:

```
POST /twitter/tweet/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "fquery": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "user:/[Cc][nN][nN]/",
                    "lowercase_expanded_terms": false 

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or on nest code it would be something on these lines

```
q.QueryString(
      d =>
        d.Query(string.Format("{0}:{1}", propertyPath,
          GetCaseInsentitiveRegexExpression(queryTerm))).LowercaseExpendedTerms(false))
```